# How do I find items and aggregate them when they meet a conditions in one table and still do a join to another table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to show how many customer_ids have receipts over 50 dollars (found from the "receipt" table: column name "customer_id", and column name: "total_price") and join that to the "customers" table which has a column that lists states. I'd like to count those "rcpt_over_50" per customer_id and list their state. 
Heres what i have:

```
SELECT customers.state, round(avg(over_50),2) AS rcpts_over_50
FROM ( 
     SELECT receipts.customer_id, receipts.total_price, customers.state,
     CASE 
         WHEN CAST(total_price AS numeric) >= 50 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS rcpts_over_50
     FROM receipts
     LEFT JOIN customers
     ON receipts.customer_id = receipts.customer_id) as TEMP
 GROUP BY customers.state
```

I keep getting the error:"relation "receipts" does not exist"

What should I do

receipts table:

```
receipt_id customer_id total_price
0000      00003         3.00    
0001      00002        75.25    
0002      00003        50.00
0003      00002        54.25   
0004      00010        60.00
```

customers:

```
customer_id state  
00003       NY    
00002       OK    
00010       NY
```

Desired output shows the number of receipts over 50 for each customer id and their respective state:

```
customer_id rcpt_over_50    state
00002       2               OK
00003       1               NY
00010       1               NY
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: First and foremost, in the outer query, you should be using TEMP and not the other tables/aliases as that's all the outer query sees is 1 "table" named "temp". Secondly, It cannot find the receipts table, so you may consider appending the schema name to that table like "from schema.receipts" where "schema" is the actual schema name (e.g. public)

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=97e0933b0aaba8f4d94661300d70251e)

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(*) as rcpt_over_50, c.state -- B
FROM receipts r
JOIN customers c
ON c.customer_id = r. customer_id                       -- A
     AND r.total_price >= 50
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.state
ORDER BY rcpt_over_50 DESC, customer_id                 -- C
```

A: The (inner) join eliminates all receipts with `total_cost < 50`.

B: Then you only need to `GROUP` the `customer_id`s and count the rows.

C: At the end you might order the result (here I used the descending order you mentioned in the question)

---

Notice that it is never a good idea to store IDs in your way. Please use simple integer type instead of left padding text. It is much more efficient for calculations and storage. And think about ids that become larger than 100000